# Decrypted file has strange characters after AES CBC decryption process

Tags: c++, encryption, istream, crypto++

I am decrypting a file with AES CBC method using the Cryptopp library in vc++, VS2015 and QT libraries. I could obtain a result file decrypted but there are some characters which are not being decrypted correctly.

The code I use is:

```
const std::string encrypted_file("C:\\TEMP\\G0030013.xml");
const std::string decrypted_file("C:\\TEMP\\decrypted0.xml");
const int key_size(CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
const int iv_size(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption;

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter *decryptor =
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
        new CryptoPP::FileSink(decrypted_file.c_str()),
            CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING);


decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, key_size, iv, iv_size);
CryptoPP::FileSource file_source(encrypted_file.c_str(), true, decryptor);
```

The resultant xml is:

```
<BG Val="149" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="15:37" D="1"/>
<BG Val="158" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="15:39" Flg="M3" D="í/Ë‰OæÚ…f÷ûâÄò" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:00" D="1"/>
<BG Val="56" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:01" D="1"/>
<BG Val="60" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:12" D="1"/>
<BG Val="58" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:13" D="1"/>
<BG Val="56" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:16" Flg="M3" D="1"/>
<BG Val="155" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:32" D="1"/>
<BG Val="168" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:33" D="1"/>
<BG Val="155" Dt="2015-06-29" Tm="17:52" Flg="M3" D="1"/>
<BG Val="138" Dt="2015-07-03" Tm="09:00" Flg="M1" D="1"/>
<BG Val="141" Dt="2015-07-03" Tm="18:24" D="ðÂwÝfIïs¯¤eåˆöm5" Dt="2015-07-06" Tm="08:28" Flg="M1" D="1"/>
<BG Val="147" Dt="2013-10-18" Tm="08:40" Ctrl="?" D="1"/>
<BG Val="142" Dt="2015-11-19" Tm="10:57" Ctrl="?" D="1"/>
```

When it should be:

```
<BG Val="149" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="15:37" D="1"/>
<BG Val="158" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="15:39" Flg="M3" D="1"/>
<BG Val="57" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:00" D="1"/>
<BG Val="56" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:01" D="1"/>
<BG Val="60" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:12" D="1"/>
<BG Val="58" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:13" D="1"/>
<BG Val="56" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:16" Flg="M3" D="1"/>
<BG Val="155" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:32" D="1"/>
<BG Val="168" Dt="2014-01-14" Tm="16:33" D="1"/>
<BG Val="155" Dt="2015-06-29" Tm="17:52" Flg="M3" D="1"/>
<BG Val="138" Dt="2015-07-03" Tm="09:00" Flg="M1" D="1"/>
<BG Val="141" Dt="2015-07-03" Tm="18:24" D="1"/>
<BG Val="135" Dt="2015-07-06" Tm="08:28" Flg="M1" D="1"/>
<BG Val="147" Dt="2013-10-18" Tm="08:40" Ctrl="?" D="1"/>
<BG Val="142" Dt="2015-11-19" Tm="10:57" Ctrl="?" D="1"/>
```

I am wondering if there is a Charset issue and it exist a way to read the encrypted file from hexadecimal to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Seems very odd thats its only the value of the `D` attribute, which remains correctly quoted.

Comment: try using the ISO/IEC 9797-1 padding. also make sure you use the same padding for decryption and encryption

Comment: Is it always 16 bytes? (`‰` and `…` are both two-bytes UTF-8 characters `U+2030` and `U+2026`)

Comment: Thanks @Behrooz , how can I use this kind of padding? In the CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme there are 5 options avalilable: ZEROS_PADDING,PKCS_PADDING,ONE_AND_ZEROS_PADDING,NO_PADDING and DEFAULT_PADDING.

Comment: @YSC Yes, it is always 16 bytes characters, but I am not sure we are talking about the same 16 bytes.

Comment: @Behrooz Padding only adds bytes to the end of the data and can only affect the last 16 bytes so it is not a padding problem. Additionally the most common padding for AES is PKCS#7 née PKCS#5.

Comment: We need to see (1) keying, (2) encryption, (3) saving the encrypted text, (4) decryption, and (5) reading the decrypted text. I think you've only provided (4) and (5).

Answer (score 2):

It is not the encryption, encryption just works on 8-bit bytes ad has no concept of what they are.

Padding only adds bytes to the end of the data and can only affect the last 16 bytes so it is not a padding problem.

It could be a difference in the string encoding, the string to be encrypted is converted to bytes based on an encoding and after decryption the bytes are re-encoded to a string with sone encoding.

Comment: Yes, but the Filesource in crypto++ is getting the name of the encrypted file and I don't know if it is getting hexadecimal values or char values depending of a charset. That is the reason I want to read the file stream as hexadecimal but I don't know how.

Comment: Looks at the contents of the file of the file with a hex editor program. Since only a portion is corrupted the best bet is that the file is corrupted. Look at the decrypted data again with a hex editor. Sorry but hex still exists and is the best way to look at the actual bytes.

Comment: Thanks @zaph . I don't think it is a file corrupted because I generate the result with another software and it is decrypting OK. In a hex editor I cannot see any suspicious because it is encrypted.

Comment: As I also stated: Look at the decrypted data with a hex editor. Especially the hex of `í/Ë‰OæÚ…f÷ûâÄò` and correctly decoded data to possibly decree the encoding. But yeah, hex is so old school.

Comment: This might be a character encoding problem that occurred long before encryption/decryption. Its odd that its only surfacing on one or two particular character(s). Maybe UTF-8 should be used consistently, and not a Windows code page.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look right:

```
const int key_size(CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
const int iv_size(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
```

I don't think its illegal, its just unusual. I think you are getting 1 int initialized to the value (either `AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH` or `AES::BLOCKSIZE`).

Usually you do something like:

```
// Memory is allocated
SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

// Set them to 0
memset(key, 0x00, key.size());
memset(iv, 0x00, iv.size());
```

Then, if you only copy 14-bytes into `key`, the two tail bytes will be in a known state.

Based on the above, I'm guessing you are using some garbage for the keys.

---

> ... CryptoPP::FileSource file_source(encrypted_file.c_str(), ...

In general, you have to be careful of using `c_str()` because there's no telling when an embedded NULL can show up in the plain text or the cipher text. You should be OK for the code above when using it as a filename. But here's some plain text that includes an embedded NULL:

```
std::string plain("asdfg\0hjkl", 10);
```

Better, use the overload of the source, filters and sinks that take either (1) the `byte*` (data) and `size_t` (length); or (2) the `std::string` (not the C-string). (2) uses `string::data` and `string::length` so embedded NULLs don't fool the machinery.

Maybe something like the following from [CBC Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_mode) on the Crypto++ wiki:

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
e.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), iv );

// The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding
//  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded
//  to the block size of the cipher.
StringSource ss( plain, true, 
    new StreamTransformationFilter( e,
        new StringSink( cipher )
    ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
); // StringSource
```

And:

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
d.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), iv );

// The StreamTransformationFilter removes
//  padding as required.
StringSource ss( cipher, true, 
    new StreamTransformationFilter( d,
        new StringSink( recovered )
    ) // StreamTransformationFilter
); // StringSource
```

Instead of a `StringSink`, you can simply use a `FileSink`:

```
... new FileSink(decrypted_file.c_str())
```

---

CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and it does not detect tampering. Usually, you want to detect tampering too. To that end, check out [EAX mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/EAX_Mode), [CCM mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CCM_Mode) and [GCM mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode). Also see [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: If the key was wrong there would not be any correct decryption. Additionally most implementations will either null pad the key or return a key length error. My bet is on a streaming problem. Unfortunately the OP will not provide any hex dumps the original, encrypted or decrypted data.

Comment: *"If the key was wrong there would not be any correct decryption..."* - or a partial decryption. *"most implementations will either null pad the key..."* - not C++. He may be getting lucky with some memory that's mostly zeros. He is claiming the key is sized properly with `const int key_size(CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH)` and `decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, key_size, iv, iv_size)`. *"will not provide any hex dumps the original, encrypted or decrypted data..."* - yea, we need to see more of what's going on.

Comment: Hello @jww , thanks for your big effort. First, I have defined the key and the IV as "const byte key[]" in another part of the code because I use always the same key vector and I can not use a random or 0's vector as you propose. Regarding the input issue, I am using filesourse of cryptopp to provide my file to the algorithm and the .c_str() function is only used to give the name of the file. I don't know how th library gets the data inside the file, that's my main problem.

Comment: @zaph I could not provide the hexadecimal of my source files, sorry. I really appreciate your help.